# FadeIn offscreen elements which were loaded later

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I wan't to fade in elements while scrolling down. Also it exists the possibility to add more elements by clicking on a button.
The problem is, that once the elements which are appended are offscreen, they wont be animated nor even displayed.

It occurs with wow.js as scrollReveal.js and any other so it seems to be a general problem, but I couldn't exactly figure out why it happens.

Here a

### **[sample](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZYpqjE)**

so you see the exact problem.

Just press **a few times** the add button.

**Edit**

So, the problem was, that I had multiple div containers nested into each other **and** using a scrollbar plugin. It doesn't matter which - each will produce this problem. I've fixed the problem by changing one line in the scrollReveal.js - Line 78:

```
viewport: window.document.documentElement, // <HTML> element by default.
```

to

```
viewport: window.document.getElementById('right'), // it's my custom container-div
```

Now it works how supposed.

If you encounter a similar problem with any scrollbarplugin or wow.js it should also fix your problem. Just change the corresponding viewport.

Comment: It seems, that the css transition is not triggered correctly .. hmm

Comment: You solved the issue?

Comment: Not really, but I know now why it happens. I'm not sure that it is easily fixable, because it also is depending on how you layout your site and seem to be an individual problem of mine, but if I solve it I will post the solution because I'm sure other people will also encounter the problem (Basically it's because the container div uses `height: 100%` the offset of the elements can't be correctly be computed and therefor don't fade in when you scroll down)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem was, that I had multiple div containers nested into each other **and** using a scrollbar plugin. It doesn't matter which - each will produce this problem. I've fixed the problem by changing one line in the scrollReveal.js - Line 78:

```
viewport: window.document.documentElement, // <HTML> element by default.
```

to

```
viewport: window.document.getElementById('right'), // it's my custom container-div
```

Now it works how supposed.

If you encounter a similar problem with any scrollbarplugin or wow.js it should also fix your problem. Just change the corresponding viewport.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is, if `window.sr = new ScrollReveal()` is called every time a new element is added, all the references to elements which has data-sr is removed and only the last element's reference will be saved.

Instead you can call `window.sr.init(true);`. For more details visit this github project https://github.com/julianlloyd/scrollReveal.js/blob/master/scrollReveal.js

Here is the working pen with above change : [CodePen](http://codepen.io/clickdilip/pen/MYjLQM)

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but as I told you I figured it out and it has nothing to do with what you have posted. I already also tried all of that and sadly the sample doesn't really summarizes my problem correctly anymore.

Comment: This is just a hack. I couldn't find a valid solution so far.

Comment: You should update the question with what you figured out so that the community can help you out.

Comment: You should read my last comment on the post. But you're right. I will do it later, right now I don't have time